# Formatting Dates in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am currently trying to convert a date from the one displayed in regedit to a readable datetime format. But I do not know how to do this, I'm working with the following:

.GetValue('InstallDate')

And in the .csv file, it display it as this: 20150914

How would I go about converting that into a readable date?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the whole code where you take the value from registry and place it in the csv (not that I would not know how to do it, I am more curious about how you do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
[datetime]::Parseexact("20150914","yyyyMMdd", $null  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you down voted the other answer because he is right on the money with `[Datetime]::ParseExact` you will have to deal with the null values though

```
    $Regbase = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
    foreach ($entry in $regBase)
    {
    $date = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\$entry | select installdate).installdate
        try
        {
            [DateTime]::ParseExact($date, "yyyyMMdd", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) 
        }
        catch [exception] 
        {
            "Date Value: $date" 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell Date is just .NET DateTime. Check [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact("20151010", "yyyyMMdd", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Where would I place that? - this is the complete string:   

($RegBase.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$_")).GetValue('InstallDate')